# Account Linking With IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I'm investigating IdentityServer3, and I'm wondering if there is built in support for a specific scenario that I'd like to implement.  The flow is as follows:

1. User signs into IdentityServer, using Identity1 and is issued access
   tokens for our application.
2. User navigates to a "Link Identity" Page,
   where they can choose to link an identity to their account
3. While signed in with Identity1, the user enters credentials for Identity2
   to prove that they own Identity2
4. Using the Identity2 information, my application links the two accounts
   to the same account.

Is this type of account linking supported OOTB with IdentityServer3, and if so, which features should I use.

If not, any advice on how to proceed?  The main challenge that I'm unsure how to pull off using IdentityServer3 is handling the "double sign in" (e.g. authenticating as Identity2 while already signed in as Identity1)

Comment: I don't see that you necessarily need to perform a "full signin" for Identity2.  Don'y you only need to verify that the username and password are correct, and then perform the linking logic that you need?

Comment: That's correct that's all I need to do, I still want to be operating in the context of Identity1.  So I guess you're implying I don't have to do the sign-in for Identity2 in the context of IdentityServer's login pages?

Answer (score 2):

All account management functions (registration, password reset, account linking, etc) are all specifically not the job of IdentityServer. This is something you'd need to build into your own application (which would commonly be a client application to IdentityServer). This client application would simply need to be able to update the database that is being used by IdentityServer for its authentication and profile data.